# How to run two functions concurrently from one route in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, heroku, concurrency, sinatra

I'm trying to understand Ruby concurrency with Sinatra app.
Here it is:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/a' do
    sleep 10
    "result_a"
end

get '/b' do
    "result_b"
end
```

If I run it as `ruby app.rb` or `shotgun app.rb` and then go to both **/a** and then **/b** - **/b** will not be loaded until **/a** executes and loads itself.
When I deploy this app to Heroku though, and go to  **/a** then **/b**, **/b** is loaded immediately.
As I understand it, Heroku process is *concurrent* (or *multithreaded*?) as opposed to my local processes.

My questions are: how to run my app concurrently on local server? 
Is it possible to run, eg, two functions concurrently from one route?

Answer (score 1):

Install Unicorn.

```
gem install unicorn
```

The [official docs](http://unicorn.bogomips.org) aren't great but you can find plenty of tutorials showing you how to configure and start up parallel server processes that will allow you to serve multiple requests concurrently.

It works by forking your process, which means that it's completely thread-safe, but also means that concurrent requests won't share memory state with each other. In fact, they won't share memory at all, so if your app has a truly enormous memory footprint (e.g. some kind of in-memory database) you will need a different solution. Otherwise, Unicorn is a very popular and reliable concurrency tool for Ruby web apps; it may actually be what is allowing Heroku to exhibit the concurrency you're seeing.

Comment: Ah. No. It sounds like you may need to use Ruby's `Thread` capability. What you're working on is a fairly tricky problem, but not impossible.

Comment: And Unicorn will allow me to run multiple functions simultaneously from one route? [got it, Ruby's `Thread`, thank you]

Comment: Unicorn will allow you to run two separate pieces of code from the same route concurrently, or the same piece of code twice concurrently. It depends on what you have your route set up to do. Unicorn will not, however, allow you to act on the same object in memory from the context of the two separate requests.

Comment: hm, it sounds good then - I already have websockets for interacting with view while keeping a browser session, now I only need my Watir pages to open concurrently. I think that could work.